# Javascript change style element on html

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I inject document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "red"; in developers console in firefox, background becomes red. But when I do webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"body\")[0].style.background = \"red\";"); in android webview, whole content in it gets replaced by the word "red". Why is background color not changing and content is being replaced? Also, how can I change the style properties in webview using javascript?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the html?

Comment: Seems it can be handled with a toggle flag.

Comment: You had a clear question, then you edited it to make it less clear? Initially you were talking about changing `color`. Now you ask merely for changing "div style".

Comment: Can you edit the question title?

Comment: Please do not completely change your question after people have given up their time to answer you.

Comment: ok please answer me now

Comment: Your question was completely changed at least 2 times. Maybe nobody wants to answer, now.

Comment: @Miladfaraji - please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Help us to help you by being clear about the nature of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's not currently, because currently you have no code to enforce this.

It's a matter of thinking through how something like this might be achieved. You have an initial state, then you move away from that state.

The information pertaining to the initial state is lost, so you need to save it somehow.

So we might use a variable storing the initial colour:

```
var init_colour = '#000';
function abc() {
    var
    el = document.getElementById("test"),
    colour_to_apply = !el.style.color ? 'red' : init_colour;
    el.style.color = colour_to_apply;
}
```

Note how we check which colour to apply - the original state, or the changed state (red). We do this by seeing if it's already been given a value for its `style.color` property. If it has, we know it's already red (i.e. this is not the first time it's been clicked) and revert to the initial colour. If it hasn't, it's the first time, or it has previously been reverted, so we apply the changed state (red) colour.

Comment: Ha... great, I literally answered the initial question he asked. Now the quesiton has changed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("test").style.color === 'red') {
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = "black";
} else {
    document.getElementById("test").style.color = "red";
}
```